# What does "HQ" from WineHQ mean?

Tags: windows, wine, emulation

This is just a curiousity, and I wasn't able to find it anywhere...

Would it be "High Quality"?

I also see that the going-to-be Mac OS Wine-like app [DarlingHQ](http://www.darlinghq.org/) also has this HQ...

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu? WINE == an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator" . HQ is a common appreviation for HeadQuarters, but you would have to ask winehq.org as I could not confirm the HQ part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headquarters.

It's the name given to the website, not the software project per se.

Comment: Also seen in GitLab: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq